# React-Native + Firebase, write and read while logged in and read only otherwise

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to make an ad page which everyone can read but only if you are logged in you're able to make a new ad page. I'm using react-native and firebase as database.
As of now I can write to the database if I'm logged in but I can't read anything from the database.

I'm not sure how to write the fetch path since when a user post it executes this path, with a ${currentUser} tag

```
  firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/ads`)
```

Here are the rules for the firebase

```
{
 "rules": {
  ".read": "true",
    "users": {
     "$uid": {
      ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

And here is the fetch code in react-native

```
export const publicAdFetch = () => {
 return (dispatch) => {
  firebase.database().ref('/users/ads')
   .on('value', snapshot => {
   dispatch({ type: PUBLICADS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: snapshot.val() 
  });
 });
 };
};
```

EDIT*****

This worked nicely, however I would like to have a dispatch method outside the Object.keys method. I want to collect the values and return them once to a list that display all of the object.

```
export const publicAdFetch = () => {
 return (dispatch) => {
  firebase.database().ref('/users').once('value').then((snapshot) => {
   const ads = snapshot.val();
    Object.keys(ads).map((objectKey, index) => {
    const value = ads[objectKey];
    console.log(value);
    dispatch({ type: PUBLICADS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: value });
   });
 });
};
};
```

Comment: Your current read doesn't work because `'/users/ads'` doesn't exist. You could fetch from `'/users'` and filter the bit you want client side or maybe you can change your datastructure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know react but I think that you are not using the correct reference:

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/users')
```

shall either:

1. include the userId if you want the reader to read the ads of a specific user, i.e. `ref('users/' + userId + '/ads')`, or
2. be `firebase.database().ref('/users')` if you want to get all the ads

---

EDIT following your comment:

Again I don't know react so I can't give you the exact code, but what you get is indeed an Object that represent the full "users" node, including all the usersIds and their children ads.

If (in pure javascript) you do as follow, you will display in the console the object under each userId .

```
firebase.database().ref('/users').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {

    var ads = snapshot.val();

    Object.keys(ads).map(function(objectKey, index) {
        var value = ads[objectKey];
        console.log(value);
    });
});
```

If you share more info on the data structure under the userId nodes and what you exactly want to disopaly it may e possible to give you more info on how to get it.

---

EDIT following your edit

You should build your payload in the Object.key() method and pass it after it is finished, like:

```
export const publicAdFetch = () => {
return (dispatch) => {
  firebase.database().ref('/users').once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    const ads = snapshot.val();
    let payload;
    Object.keys(ads).map((objectKey, index) => {
      const value = ads[objectKey];
      console.log(value);
      payload =+ value; //Probably it should be more complex here 
      //than just concatenating the values
      //depending on the payload format you need to e.g. build an array or an object
    });
    dispatch({ type: PUBLICADS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: payload });
  });
};
```

};

Comment: I want to be able to read all the ads from all the users when I'm not logged in. When I did 
      firebase.database().ref('/users')   
I get a response from the debugger telling me that I've fetched the object, but i can't see the content of the objects in my App.

Comment: my payload requires that I add Object only, and it seems 
payload =+ value; dosen't work for my two objects.

Comment: @Japaleno That's what I thought, too, hence my comment in the code. You will then have to work with the objects you get through the Object.keys(ads).map() method to build the workload as you need. An alternative is to use another approach to (i.e. not this Object.keys(ads).map() method) but in any case you will have to work on javascript objects in order to build you payload object.